# SELECT баз + базы в Always On

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется скрипт

```
select
ag.name as aag_name,
ar.replica_server_name,
d.name as [database_name],
hars.is_local,
hars.synchronization_state_desc as synchronization_state,
hars.synchronization_health_desc as synchronization_health,
hars.last_commit_time,
CASE  is_local
 WHEN 1 then 'Primary'
 WHEN 0 then 'Secondary'
end
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states as hars
 join sys.availability_replicas as ar
on hars.replica_id = ar.replica_id
 join sys.availability_groups as ag
on ag.group_id = hars.group_id
 join sys.databases as d
on d.group_database_id = hars.group_database_id
 order by aag_name, replica_server_name`
```

Выводит базы состоящие в Always On.
Как можно сделать вывод всех баз, а уже в нем чтобы был столбец с наличием Always On?

Comment: Заменить: `join sys.databases as d` --> `right join sys.databases as d`

Comment: Спасибо большое!